# How to show the misclassification rate/false positive/false negative after train a model in R caret?

Tags: r-caret, false-positive

I trained a classification model using treebag:

```
tbmodel <- train(target ~ ., data = combine_train, method = "treebag")
predictors <- names(trainSplit)[names(trainSplit) != 'target']

pred <- predict(tbmodel$finalModel, testSplit[,predictors])
```

How can  I get the misclassification rate, false positive, negative rate of this model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is [plenty of documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html) on this.